# python writing a list to a file incorrectly

Tags: python, text-processing, bioinformatics

I am having an issue with writing a list to a file. I am annotating certain files to change them into a certain format, so I read sequence alignment files, store them in lists, do necessary formatting, and then write them to a new file. The problem is that while my list, containing sequence alignments is structured correctly, the output produced when it writes them to new files is incorrect (it does not replicate my list structure). I include only a section of my output and what it should look like because the list itself if far too long to post.

OUTPUT WRITTEN TO FILE:

```
>
TRFE_CHICK 

From XALIGN

MKLILCTVLSLGIAAVCFAAP (seq spans multiple lines) ...

ADYIKAVSNLRKCS--TSRLLEAC*> (end of sequence, * should be on a newline, followed by > on a newline as well)
```

OUTPUT IS SUPPOSED TO BE WRITTEN AS:

```
>

TRFE_CHICK

From XALIGN

MKLILCTVLSLGIAAVCFAAP (seq spans many lines) ...

ADYIKAVSNLRKCS--TSRLLEAC

*

>
```

It does this misformatting multiple times over.  I have tried pickling and unpickling the list but that misformats it further.

My code for producing the list and writing to file:

```
new = []
for line in alignment1:
    if line.endswith('*\n'):
        new.append(line.strip('*\n'))
        new.append('*')
   else:
        new.append(line)

new1 = []
for line in new:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        twolines = line[0] + '\n' + line[1:]
        new1.append(twolines)
        continue
    else:
        new1.append(line)

for line in new1:
     alignfile_annot.write(line)
```

Basically, I have coded it so that it reads the alignment file, inserts a line between the end of the sequence and the * character and also so that > followed by the ID code are always on new lines. This is the way my list is built but not the way it is written to file. Anyone know why the misformatting? 
Apologies for the long text, I tried to keep it as short as possible to make my issue clear
I'm running Python 2.6.5

Comment: Can you provide the sample input?  I imagine you can achieve this result with much less code.

Comment: The input is an ASCII file that contains a multiple sequence alignment. The input goes something like this: >TRFE_HUMAN ... a very long sequence followed by *  on a new line >TRFE_MOUSE ... another long sequence followed by * . The code is long because there are a lot of formatting details I need to care for, such as splitting > and TRFE_MOUSE into two lines, and putting the * on a newline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new.append(line.strip('*\n'))
new.append('*')
```

You have a list of lines (with newline terminators each), so you need to include \n for these two lines, too:

```
new.append(line[:-2] + "\n")  # slice as you just checked line.endswith("*\n")
new.append("*\n")
```

Remember the strip (or slice, as I've changed it to) will remove the newline, so splitting a single item in the list with a value of "...*\n" into two items of "..." and "*" actually *removes* a newline from what you had originally.

Comment: Thank you! I had not realized that my code was removing a newline from the list instead of inserting one and appending the *

Comment: Can I ask something else, among the output I am trying to write to the file are strings containing numbers e.g '48', '50'. In a script you would normally write str(48), \ str(50) , using the line continuation character to print them out as 48 50. How can I reproduce this when writing to a file? I use the continuation character but it doesn't work. I basically just need to the file have the line (for example) 48 50 .

Comment: @Spyros: "+" is used in Python to concatenate strings.

Comment: Yes, is it possible to concatenate a whitespace character though? something like str(48) + '' str(50) produces an error. And the str(48), \ str(50) syntax does not create the whitespace when I use it inside the write() method

Comment: @Spyros: Do you want "48" + " " + "50"? Also read up on string formatting with both the % operator and str's format method.